# angularJS input text box : default value

Tags: html, angularjs

In angularJs, i have a input text box, how do i set the default value? I tried `ng-init:searchText` it failed.

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myController">
        <p>
            <label>username : </label>
            <input type="text" ng-model="username" name="username" id="username" ng-init:searchText="default value" />
        </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ngValue directive](https://www.javatpoint.com/angularjs-ng-value-directive) or init it via the `ng-model` property on the scope